# Python Tornado website brackets not parsed

Tags: python, tornado

I'm using tornado and might website works locally, when I move the entire directory to an windows server with IIS and run up my website it loses all the styles from bootstrap. I then looked at the debugger and it appears the "{{ }}" brackets are not being resolved by tornado. Can anyone sugggest why?

[image]

The only difference I see is locally I refer to the site as http://localhost:8080 and on the server I get to it by http://servername/thea which is the directory where all the code is.

Comment: Are you sure that it's working on your local computer? Because you have the template syntax all wrong. You've got the quotes in wrong places - `src="{{" static_ur("...") }}`. It should be like `src="{{ static_url("...") }}"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `'` (single-quotes) in place of `"` (double-quotes) inside the tag.

like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ static_url('bootstrap-4.0.0 bootstrap.min.css') }}">
```

Comment: I don't think that's going to help. Anyway, your answer was crucial in bringing the mistakes in OP's code to notice.

Comment: This wasn't the reason for failure. The syntax was correct, it is just how it looks in Chrome after it has not been passed by tornados template system. The problem was that I was not connecting to the port http://servername:8888. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

You say that it works locally -- my guess is by running something like `python application.py` -- but it fails when you "move the entire directory to an windows server with IIS". Simply moving the directory will not actually deploy your application on Windows -- it will just publish your files statically, which is why you're getting the above source code in your browser.

In order to [deploy your Tornado site on IIS](http://www.helicontech.com/articles/running-wsgi-on-iis/) you need to [wrap it](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/running.html#wsgi-and-google-app-engine) in  `tornado.wsgi.WSGIAdapter` first.

Comment: This wasn't the reason for failure. The syntax was correct, it is just how it looks in Chrome after it has not been passed by tornados template system. The problem was that I was not connecting to the port http://servername:8888. Simple as that.

Comment: When you accessed the site on the wrong port (probably 80, which is default for HTTP), IIS apparently served the template file statically, without parsing it through the Tornado engine.

Answer (score -1):

Answer, I was just missing the port. Then tornado passed the template "{{ }}" correctly and the static files were found.